# Run ssh-add after Yakuake is opened by startup script

Tags: scripts, ssh, yakuake

I'm using Ubuntu's [Startup Applications](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html) feature to run a script at startup. The script looks like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

dropBoxDevDir=/home/mitch/Dropbox/dev

set -e

yakuake &
python $dropBoxDevDir/scripts/ysess -i $dropBoxDevDir/configs/yakuake.ini
ssh-add
```

The idea is to:

1. Run [`yakuake`](https://www.kde.org/applications/system/yakuake/)
2. Run the [`ysess`](https://bitbucket.org/eternicode/yakuake-sessions/overview) script to open some tabs in Yakuake
3. Run `ssh-add` so that I can perform Git operations later on

The problem is that `ssh-add` doesn't seem to get run. How can I figure out why it doesn't get run?

Alternatively, is there a better way to run `ssh-add` after the other two commands have finished?

Comment: what do you mean by "later on"? There is nothing "later on" in this script.

Comment: Does it matter? It's not related to the question. The question is clearly stated in the last two sentences.

Comment: Yes. It does matter. It also matters if the ssh-agent or gnome keyring is already started in the startup script. And it also matters where the startup script should read the passphrapses for the encrytpted keys from.

Comment: As mentioned, I want to perform Git operations (e.g. `git push`) on repositories that are cloned with the `git:` protocol, which require me to use my SSH key. If I run `ssh-add` once beforehand, I can avoid the need to type my password each time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've found an answer by now, but I saw this unanswered so...

I see 2 potential causes.

1. I don't see where you've started ssh-agent. Looking at the man page for ssh-add it adds keys to a running ssh-agent, so that agent must be started first.
2. Additionally the man page for ssh-add states that if no  keys are given it will install some default keys, so if the agent is indeed running, I'd make sure those are the keys you want.

I used these commands for help:

```
man ssh-add
man ssh-agent
```

Hope this helps!